# Haskell Bytestring to Float Array

Tags: haskell, bytestring

Hi have binaries of float data (single-precision 32-bit IEEE) that I would like to work on.
How can I best load this for further use, ideally as (IOArray Int Float).

```
bytesToFloats :: ByteString -> [Float]
bytesToFloatArray :: ByteString -> IOArray Int Float
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got bog standard single-precision floats, and you just want to work them over in Haskell, you can always be down and dirty about it:

```
import Data.ByteString.Internal as BS
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable as V

bytesToFloats :: BS.ByteString -> V.Vector Float
bytesToFloats = V.unsafeCast . aux . BS.toForeignPtr
  where aux (fp,offset,len) = V.unsafeFromForeignPtr fp offset len
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be happier with Data.Vector:

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell:_A_Vector_Tutorial#Parsing_Binary_Data

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [cereal](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal) library, for example:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.ByteString
import Data.Serialize

floatsToBytes :: [Float] -> ByteString
floatsToBytes = runPut . mapM_ putFloat32le

-- | Parses the input and returns either the result or an error description.
bytesToFloat :: ByteString -> Either String [Float]
bytesToFloat = runGet $ many getFloat32le
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can convert 4 bytes to a `Word32`, you can use the function `wordToFloat` in the [`data-binary-ieee754`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-binary-ieee754-0.4.4) package to convert it to a float.  You could then load this into any kind of list-like structure you want to manipulate it.